# Shared gradle project in spring boot does not contain yml files

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have projects `A` and `B` that both have `common` project as a compile dependency defined in their build.gradle files like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":common")


    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
    compile("net.oauth.core:oauth:20090617")
    compile("net.oauth.core:oauth-httpclient4:20090617")
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient')
    compile("com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client:2.0.0-m2")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:18.0")
    compile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

This common project has application.yml file with all kind of common information such as database connection properties, hibernate setup, etc. So I do not want to duplicate these files all over the other projects such as `A` and `B`.

In project `A` the main spring boot file looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {CommonApp.class,
        A.class})
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(A.class, args);
    }
}
```

where `CommonApp` is a main class in the `commmon` project. This `common` main file is the following:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class CommonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommonApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Projects `A` and `B` compile just fine, but all `yml` files that are in the classpath of the `common` project are not visible from `A` and `B`, so I have not choice but to duplicate them manually in `A` and `B`

What is the better approach? Can spring boot common projects share resources with other projects?

Notice that ideally solution should not be gradle dependant as I would like to run unit and integration tests from Intellij IDEA which does not use gradle for running tests.

My app structure is

```
app
 |-A
   |-build.gradle
 |-web
    |-B
      |-build.gradle
 |-common
    |-src/main/resources
                |-application.yml
                |-database.yml
                |-web.yml
 |-settings.gradle
 |-build.gradle
```

A, B and common are all spring boot apps (common is a boot app too, but it's only used as a dependency for A, B).

Comment: Can you show the folder structure of the common project? Are you packaging your yaml files into the jars you publish?

Comment: No, I am not packaging yaml into the jars, how can I do that? Doesn't the gradle script do it out of the box?

Comment: non-code files are included in jars automatically *only* if they are placed in the standard resources folder (`src/main/resources`), or their location is added to the sourceset as a resource location.  In the structure you listed above, where do the yaml files live?

Comment: yes, sorry. I added yml files to the list too. I have no custom resources sourceset folder added in my project in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-gradle solution, you could always add a DAO-esque file to access the required values in the common project then jar your common project and add it as a dependency to projects A and B.

Edit: I apologize, I did not explain very well. When I say "DAO-esque file", what I mean to say is a file of getter (and setters if needed) that access the properties file. For example, have a getter file that is a singleton. On creation, create a static reference to the property file. When Project A (or B) needs a property, it can call to this file to get the property.

As for a gradle solution, it looks like your above is fairly close with your

```
compile project(":common")
```

code. Do you have a settings.gradle file that has the line

```
includeFlat "common"
```

and a reference to the common project in the same directory as Project A and B? For example

Project A

(...Project A's files...)

Project B

(...Project B's files...)

Common
  (...Common's files...)

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more what is this DAO-esque file? Also, what would be a gralde solution for this?

Comment: The thing is that I have my properties defined in a bean marked with `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation, but the problem is that this bean's getters return null because there's no underlying properties file that this bean references to. If you could give some code snippet of what your thought was then I might make things a bit clearer.

Comment: As for the gradle approach, I have a `include "common"` in the settings file, not `includeFlat` thought. Also I did not understand quite well what reference do you mean in "reference to the common project in the same directory as Project A and B" sentence?